# Using Javascript in visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I'd like to start using Visual Studio for Mac with Javascript, but I'm not quite sure how I would start seeing as I only see prompts for using C# or F# and the like. Do I need to download something else or is this feature offered for the Mac version?

Comment: What do you mean by _using javascript in VS_? VS text editor can be used to write javascript by default.

Comment: Should I just open a javascript file with it? On my version I don't get an option to start JS project the same as it does a C# or F# project.

Comment: You need to install useful modules, such as Javascript (ES6) code snippets,  etc. which will make your coding much more comfortable.

Comment: Oh, it appears there's a Marketplace for VS where you can download a ton of functionality

Comment: And there are many types of Visual Studio. I have the Mac Community on and I needed the Visual Studio Code version...

Answer (score 1):

When you create a project (such as web forms) in Visual studio, add a JS item and there you can work on it.

If you want a light program that works perfectly fine with HTML, CSS, JS
Download
[Brackets](http://brackets.io/)